# What is the economically efficient hardware setup for proof-of-stake mining?

Tags: mining, proof-of-stake, hardware

As I understand it, if/when proof-of-stake is fully adopted, all those GPUs will become practically worthless for mining. (Presumably they'll be dumped onto the secondhand market or redeployed for POW mining on competing currencies.

If I was to build a good POS mining rig from scratch, what are the priority requirements? Where is the advantage? Would I want many cores, or lots of RAM, or will the computation hardware be rendered moot by network latency? Or will a "good enough" computer perform as well as any bigger/faster machine, assuming that blocks don't normally contain gas-hungry calculations?

In a nutshell: what are the hardware requirements for POS mining, and to what extent is it worthwhile to build a bigger/faster machine?

Comment: Hi there. Though you've already acknowledged a GPU probably won't be any help, and you go on to ask more specific sub-questions, I think the answer to the one I've suggested a dupe to covers your question.

Comment: @RichardHorrocks Yes, I ask more-specific sub-questions, hence this is a new question and not a duplicate.

Comment: Hi again. My point was that the answer to that question already covers it. Mainly: "PoS implementations require only that the software is running for it to vote, and very little or no computation". So basically you'll just need a reliable internet connection, rather than specialist hardware.

Comment: @RichardHorrocks I read that, it implicitly *suggests* that no specialist hardware will be *needed*, but that is not an adequate answer. I'm looking for a positive, concrete, substantiated answer. Something with actual numbers in it, basically. Please re-open the question

Comment: Hi again. I'm afraid there _are_ no actual, substantive numbers at the current time, and any explicitly stated numbers would be speculative. The exact implementation details of (Ethereum's) PoS are still unconfirmed, so the best anyone can say would likely be similar to the answer in the linked question. i.e. Given what we know about the _likely_ implementation, it won't require any specialised hardware (such as GPUs). If you replace the term "GPU" in the other question with "specialised hardware", then the two questions are almost identical, down to the sub-questions about profitability.

Comment: Of course, if others disagree with my interpretation, then they're welcome to re-open it :-)

Comment: I'm voting to reopen it for two reasons. First: We can start discussing general good practices of  current PoS networks like Dash Masternodes, NXT, firewalls, network latency and redundancy even though Casper implementation is not ready yet. Second: with the introduction of EIP 648, hardware in PoS nodes and even PoW nodes suddenly became more important as cores are needed to run parallel code. So it is likely that in the future hardware with a max amount of 8 cores will be needed. This might be a good question to contain all these recommendations.

Comment: Richard, if there are no actual, substantive numbers yet, then we can leave the question open until there are.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mine a proof of stake cryptocurrency, so having an internet connection and computer is all you need.